# How can I disable scrolling between windows if my mouse is in the xfce panel?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, xfce, scrolling, xfce-panel

My frustration is that after selecting a window button on my panel (Xubuntu 12.04), if I don't move my cursor away from the window buttons and begin scrolling (intending to scroll the content within the window), the windows manager cycles through all of the open windows.

How do I disable the window button scrolling feature?

I have tried looked in Windows Manager Settings, Windows Manager Tweaks Settings, Panel Settings, Windows Button Settings and xfwm4 settings in the Settings Editor but couldn't find anything to change it.

Online, the closest thing I have found is this [libwnck-noscroll ppa](https://launchpad.net/~libwnck-noscroll/+archive/ppa).  Despite the fact that it said it was made for older distros, I tried it and it didn't work.  Is anyone aware of another fix?

Answer (score 18):

This can be changed, but the toggle is really well hidden.

Right click on the panel, select "Panel" then "Panel Preferences".

[image]

Switch to the "Items" tab, select the "Window Buttons" item in the list and click the wrench icon.

[image]

Then uncheck "Switch windows using the mouse wheel"

[image]

You're done!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!  Yeah I had already looked there and for some reason I don't have the option there... yes I am jealous.  Are you working from the same distro as me? Or do you think my xfwm4 could be out of date?

Comment: My version of xfwm4 is 4.8.3 and xfce4-panel is 0.1 it seems.

Comment: @jamin39 I'm not at my computer right now, but I forgot to mention that I'm running Saucy so I was probably using version 4.10.1... I will check then I get back. The option might not exist in your version :-/

Comment: @jamin39 I have confirmed the option is only available in xfwm4 version 4.10. I think you might be able to upgrade xfwm *without* upgrading to 13.10, but I'm not sure as of yet.

Comment: I did it but not solved. Need to reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Enable the [ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10](https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.10) PPA and upgrade to Xfce `4.10`. Then search for the handle to the left of the `Window Buttons` panel plug-in and <kbd>right-click</kbd> on it, then `Properties`, then disable "Switch windows using the mouse wheel".